# Opening new activities with different combination of check boxes checked?

Tags: java, android

I want to make an app which has checkboxes, so what i basically want to do is that if certain checkboxes are check i want to open a certain activity. For ex; there is a question whats your gender the checkboxes available are male and female the other question is what do eat the check boxes available are pizza and burger so if male and pizza are chosen i want to open a certain activity, i want to open different activities with different combinations.how should i do this?

Comment: What have you tried where are you stuck? You need to ask a more specific question. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: how should i do that?

Comment: You should first make an attempt at this problem. Create a blank app. Try to add a checkbox. Add an action to that checkbox. Add more checkboxes and more actions. If you get stuck, google your problem. If you find no results for your specific problem, return and ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CheckBox.isChecked()` to get the current checked state`(true/false)` of the `CheckBox`. Use nested `if_else` condition to check the `CheckBox's` state and apply your logic to launch different activities.

**Try this:**

```
    if(checkBoxMale.isChecked()) {
        if(checkBoxPizza.isChecked()) {
            // Launch activity_male_pizza
        } else if(checkBoxBurger.isChecked()) {
            // Launch activity_male_burger
        } else {
            // Do something
        }
    } else if(checkBoxFemale.isChecked()){
        if(checkBoxPizza.isChecked()) {
            // Launch activity_female_pizza
        } else if(checkBoxBurger.isChecked()){
            // Launch activity_female_burger
        } else {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

**Launch new activity:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if your `CheckBox` `isChecked()`. It will return `boolean` value. Then you can set your logic and call `Intent` accordingly. You can do as below:

```
if(cbMale.isChecked() && cbPizza.isChecked){
   Intent i = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, YourNextActivity.class)
   startActivity(i);
}
```

Do as above for rest of the conditions. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(checkBoxPizza.isChecked()){
   if(checkBoxMale.isChecked()){//launch activity1}
   if(checkBoxFemale.isChecked()){//launch activity2}
}

if(checkBoxBurger.isChecked()){
   if(checkBoxMale.isChecked()){//launch activity3}
   if(checkBoxFemale.isChecked()){//launch activity4}
}
```

Use a system of this sort to determine which result you need.